# Viewing piped data inside pipe error

Tags: node.js, error-handling, pipe

In the following code block how can I log the piped data causing JSONStream.parse to fail?

```
data.pipe(JSONStream.parse('*'))
.on('error', () => {
    // here I'd like to see the data causing JOSONStream.parse to blow up
    reject("Error parsing the json!");
})
.pipe(objectStream);
```

I ask because currently when it blows up I get this sort of error message but no context to what the Invalid UTF-8 character is:

```
Error: Invalid JSON (Invalid UTF-8 character at position 2397 in state STRING1)
        at Parser.proto.write (/var/www/data-site/pop-service/node_modules/JSONStream/node_modules/jsonparse/jsonparse.js:120:31)
        at Stream.<anonymous> (/var/www/data-site/pop-service/node_modules/JSONStream/index.js:23:12)
        at Stream.stream.write (/var/www/data-site/pop-service/node_modules/JSONStream/node_modules/through/index.js:26:11)
        at IncomingMessage.ondata (_stream_readable.js:536:20)
        at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
        at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:169:7)
        at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
        at IncomingMessage.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnBody (_http_common.js:124:22)
        at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:320:20)
```

something like `.on('error', (data) => {...` doesn't seem to work

**Solution** using answer from @drinchev

```
    //save the last chunk so that we can log it in case of parsing error
    let lastRetrievedChunk = '';
    data.on('data', (dd: any) => {
      lastRetrievedChunk = dd.toString();
    });

    let jsonParser = JSONStream.parse('*');
    jsonParser.on('error', (err: any) => {
      reject(err.stack + ' lastchunk = ' + lastRetrievedChunk);
    });
    data.pipe(jsonParser).pipe(objectStream);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work indeed, since it is event-driven process.

You can try to store the data in a variable and pass it to the error

```
var someString = '*';

data.pipe(JSONStream.parse(someString))
    .on('error', () => {
       console.log( someString );
       reject("Error parsing the json!");
    })
    .pipe(objectStream);
```

At any point you can also use some library like [through2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/through2) which can help you to make a stream that logs the piped data.